# May echo / print output crash server (RAM)

Tags: python, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, opensuse

I experienced an server crash and assume that it was caused by a lack of RAM. I've programed a Basic HTTP Server with Python that accept and handles all requests of my IoT-Devices. Every single peace is logged, which causes a lot of output in debug mode. I'm using an Amazon EC2 Instace and the System-Log gave me some output like "0K upper memory".

Any idea or where I should look at?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at console screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that printing is causing the problem then you can disable logging in your base HTTP server.Printing logs often slows the server down though never heard about crashing . Make sure you are not going into infinite loop.

Add the following function in the Base http server class to disable logging.

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
        return
```